# Find all three sides of the triangle. Which satisfy a single equation.

Tags: number-theory, triangles

In the triangle $ABC$, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the sides opposite to vertices $A$, $B$, $C$.

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are natural Numbers and their $HCF$ is $1$.

If $$\dfrac{\left ( s-a \right )^{2}}{36}+\dfrac{\left ( s-b \right )^{2}}{9}+\dfrac{\left ( s-c \right )^{2}}{4}=\dfrac{s^{2}}{49}$$ where $s$ is the semi_perimeter, then find the side lengths.

Now here is my take. After rewriting the given expression 
$$ 49\left \{ \left ( s-a \right )^{2}+4\left ( s-b \right )^{2}+9\left ( s-c \right )^{2} \right \}=36s^{2} $$
we can see here $s^{2}$ is divisible by $49$.

I can not go further perhaps my number theory is very bad.
Please help me.

Comment: If $s^2$ is divisible by $49$ then $s$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Where are you getting the numbers $36, 9,4$ and $49$ from?

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\dfrac{\left ( s-a \right )^{2}}{36}+\dfrac{\left ( s-b \right )^{2}}{9}+\dfrac{\left ( s-c \right )^{2}}{4}\geq \frac{(3s-a-b-c)^2}{36+9+4}=\dfrac{s^{2}}{49}$$

Equality occurs if and only if

$$\frac{s-a}{36}=\frac{s-b}{9}=\frac{s-c}{4}$$

Can you end it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got it from here.